# SQLWorkbenchJ and Redshift execute this query forever

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I am trying to create a temporary table (using a CTE) to contain a list of all possible locales. I am executing this query in SQLWorkbenchJ build 125 on MacOS JVM 1.8

This query doesn't query any table in the database. If you copy paste this query it will execute forever. it will never print any results.

It has something to do with the size of the query. If I remove locales and only have upto the line 'en-GB' it works fine. but as you add more locales to the query, suddenly SQLWorkbenchJ will go blank and never return any results.

```
with locales(locale) as (
  select 'af-ZA'
  union 
  select 'am-ET'
  union 
  select 'ar-AE'
  union 
  select 'ar-BH'
  union 
  select 'ar-DZ'
  union 
  select 'ar-EG'
  union 
  select 'ar-IQ'
  union 
  select 'ar-JO'
  union 
  select 'ar-KW'
  union 
  select 'ar-LB'
  union 
  select 'ar-LY'
  union 
  select 'ar-MA'
  union 
  select 'arn-CL'
  union 
  select 'ar-OM'
  union 
  select 'ar-QA'
  union 
  select 'ar-SA'
  union 
  select 'ar-SY'
  union 
  select 'ar-TN'
  union 
  select 'ar-YE'
  union 
  select 'as-IN'
  union 
  select 'az-Cyrl-AZ'
  union 
  select 'az-Latn-AZ'
  union 
  select 'ba-RU'
  union 
  select 'be-BY'
  union 
  select 'bg-BG'
  union 
  select 'bn-BD'
  union 
  select 'bn-IN'
  union 
  select 'bo-CN'
  union 
  select 'br-FR'  
  union 
  select 'bs-Cyrl-BA'
  union 
  select 'bs-Latn-BA'
  union 
  select 'ca-ES'
  union 
  select 'co-FR'
  union 
  select 'cs-CZ'
  union 
  select 'cy-GB'
  union 
  select 'da-DK'
  union 
  select 'de-AT'
  union 
  select 'de-CH'
  union 
  select 'de-DE'
  union 
  select 'de-LI'
  union 
  select 'de-LU'
  union 
  select 'dsb-DE'
  union 
  select 'dv-MV'
  union 
  select 'el-GR'
  union 
  select 'en-029'
  union 
  select 'en-AU'
  union 
  select 'en-BZ'
  union 
  select 'en-CA'
  union 
  select 'en-GB'  
  union 
  select 'en-IE'
  union 
  select 'en-IN'
  union 
  select 'en-JM'
  union 
  select 'en-MY'
  union 
  select 'en-NZ'
  union 
  select 'en-PH'
  union 
  select 'en-SG'
  union 
  select 'en-TT'
  union 
  select 'en-US'
  union 
  select 'en-ZA'
  union 
  select 'en-ZW'
  union 
  select 'es-AR'
  union 
  select 'es-BO'
  union 
  select 'es-CL'
  union 
  select 'es-CO'
  union 
  select 'es-CR'
  union 
  select 'es-DO'
  union 
  select 'es-EC'
  union 
  select 'es-ES'
  union 
  select 'es-GT'
  union 
  select 'es-HN'
  union 
  select 'es-MX'
  union 
  select 'es-NI'
  union 
  select 'es-PA'
  union 
  select 'es-PE'
  union 
  select 'es-PR'
  union 
  select 'es-PY'
  union 
  select 'es-SV'
  union 
  select 'es-US'
  union 
  select 'es-UY'
  union 
  select 'es-VE'  
  union 
  select 'et-EE'
  union 
  select 'eu-ES'
  union 
  select 'fa-IR'
  union 
  select 'fi-FI'
  union 
  select 'fil-PH'
  union 
  select 'fo-FO'
  union 
  select 'fr-BE'
  union 
  select 'fr-CA'
  union 
  select 'fr-CH'
  union 
  select 'fr-FR'
  union 
  select 'fr-LU'
  union 
  select 'fr-MC'
  union 
  select 'fy-NL'
  union 
  select 'ga-IE'
  union 
  select 'gd-GB'
  union 
  select 'gl-ES'
  union 
  select 'gsw-FR'
  union 
  select 'gu-IN'
  union 
  select 'ha-Latn-NG'
  union 
  select 'he-IL'
  union 
  select 'hi-IN'
  union 
  select 'hr-BA'
  union 
  select 'hr-HR'
  union 
  select 'hsb-DE'
  union 
  select 'hu-HU'
  union 
  select 'hy-AM'
  union 
  select 'id-ID'
  union 
  select 'ig-NG'
  union 
  select 'ii-CN'
  union 
  select 'is-IS'
  union 
  select 'it-CH'
  union 
  select 'it-IT'
  union 
  select 'iu-Cans-CA'
  union 
  select 'iu-Latn-CA'
  union 
  select 'ja-JP'
  union 
  select 'ka-GE'
  union 
  select 'kk-KZ'
  union 
  select 'kl-GL'
  union 
  select 'km-KH'
  union 
  select 'kn-IN'  
)
select locale from locales limit 100;
```

Comment: Returns instantly in `psql` for me. I think your SQL client is _not_ actually submitting the query to Redshift.

Comment: yes. it runs fine in psql for me as well. this is why I tagged the question with `sql-workbench-j`

Comment: This runs instantly for me in SQL Workbench/J (I didn't test it with Redshift as I don't have access to it, but as the query doesn't touch any tables from the database this shouldn't matter)